# MVC5 can't find controller in same folder as default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]I have a routing problem. I have 3 controllers in the same folder.

```
/pages/defaultcontroller
/pages/datacontroller
/pages/infocontroller
```

All controllers have a `Index` action, and there are `index.cshtml` views in the views folder(s). The system can find the default controller but it cant find the others.

E.g. `http://servername/pages/default` works fine but `http://servername/pages/data` doesn't work and `http://servername/pages/info` doesn't work

### The error is

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

### Requested URL: /pages/info

I have this route, configured

```
context.MapRoute(
    "pages_default",
    "pages/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The only oddity is that this is an mvc portion added to an existing web-forms project as part of application migration development to mvc.

I am newish to mvc and enjoying it so far :)

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

I tried adding extra routing, still the same problem

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "pages_data",
            "pages/data/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "data", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "pages_info",
            "pages/info/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "info", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "pages_default",
            "pages/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**UPDATE(2)**

Output from route debugger (top of question)

Comment: Use `RouteDebugger` NuGet pkg and it will help you debug the problem

Comment: Check if you have correct namespace for controller names, and examine generated route by RouteDebugger. Usually this problem arise from incorrect settings in route or area configuration.

Comment: I also would not use `pages` because the controllers are not pages.

Comment: You have DefaultController in Controllers folder too?

Comment: Try putting all controller files in `Controllers` directory and see if they're work first, then configure view engine to find proper views (I tell you this is likely controller namespace problem). Using `pages` as controller parent directory deviates from MVC standard where controllers stored in `Controllers` directory & views stored in `Views` directory.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I agree and that folder is renamed now to `newpages` all the controllers are in the same folder called `controllers` which is under the newpages `/areas/newpages/controllers/...`. PS: I didn't create the 'areas' folder, VS did that for me when I added mvc to the project

Comment: PD: I also renamed the `data` folder `databank` just in case that might be messing things up

Comment: What version of IIS are you running on? Are **any** MVC routes working (or only webforms)?

Comment: @mjwills vs2013 and iisexpress from that. web-forms works fine in this project and other (unrelated) mvc projects i am working on also work fine on their own too

Comment: Does https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Mar/27/ASPNET-Routing-not-working-on-IIS-70 help?

Comment: @mjwills sadly no it doesn't I'll just reconfigure my app i think. Not ideal but its only temporary as a new app will take over at some point

Comment: The router is looking for `newpages/databank/index` where `databank` is controller. Do you have the action `index` in that controller?

Comment: @CodingYoshi if you read my original post, all my controllers have an `Index` action. I've given up on this now and just put all my actions in the `default` controller as I know that's found and works. I know it bloats that controller but I don't have any more time to fix it and its only a temp solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I renamed the folder to avoid a possible system conflict.
When I added new controllers their namespace reflected the new folder name where as the existing items have the old namespace based on the original folder name.

Once the existing files namespaces were renamed to reflect the new folder everything works. Its caused me some extra work but I am now back on track

Thanks for everyone's input

Answer (score 0):

Should your route be:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "pages_default",
    "pages/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You don't have a `controller` param defined in the defaults.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. As I don't want a default controller over all. See my update

Comment: 2 points: 1) No it does not. 2) That will not resolve the issue anyways.

Comment: @djack109 No one will know because we do not have your code. Use `RouteDebugger`. I never start a project without it. It will tell you the issue right away.

Comment: Sorry yes, good point, I think you already responded on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922221/mvc5-cant-find-controller-in-same-folder-as-default?noredirect=1#comment76821509_44922221. I am using routedebugger and its telling me that my routes are matched